# Navigation bar only collapses for one UITableView if two UITableViews are added as subviews on screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have following situation:

I Have added two tableviews on the view. Both have all constraints set to all edges (top,left,right,bottom). One is hidden at the start and the other one is not. I have put segmented control in navigation bar titleView and tapping on segmented control items triggers one tableview to hide and another one to show. Everything works fine but on iOS11 when there are large titles presented navigation bar only wants to scroll and collapse for first tableview in hierarchy, and when I change segment to other tableview navigation bar collapsing and showing loses all touch (stays on the same place).

Is there any way to fix this or is this some iOS bug/limitation?

Thanks for help :)

[image: Contacts table view in this case has ability to affect large titles navigation bar to scroll and collapse and calls table view doesnt. If I switch them the calls would affect navigation bar and contacts wouldnt.]

Contacts table view in this case has ability to affect large titles navigation bar to scroll and collapse and calls table view doesnt. If I switch them the calls would affect navigation bar and contacts wouldnt.

Answer (score 0):

The collapse feature on iOS 11 only works for UITableViews and UICollectionViews that are the first subview of the ViewController. Instead of hiding/unhiding the table views, you can instead move the top tableView to the bottom of the hierarchy (by using `insertSubview(view, at: 0)`) and hide (or remove) the previous one.